# ER graphs, expected number of triangles incident to one vertex

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I'm really sorry for this question. I'm new to a graph theory, and I hope you will help me to understand one statement.

> Consider $ER(n,p)$ graph with $n \geq 3$ and $p \in [0,1]$.
>   The statement says that the expected number of triangles incident of one vertex is $(p(n-1)(p(n-1)-1)/2)*p$.

When I'm trying to parse this statement I understand that $p(n-1)$ is the expected number of edges incident to a vertex, but when I'm trying to go further I'm getting a little bit confused! So,can you help me to read this formula and understand it? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a source for the statement?

Comment: you are absolutely correct with the simplification.I can't provide the source,because it is written in the universities book,`and I can't share the link,because of the copy rights

Comment: I am quite dubious.  Unless I'm mistaken, it should be ${{n - 1} \choose 2}p^3 = (p(n - 1)p(n - 2))/2 * p$, which is close to what you have but not the same.  Is your source reliable ?

Answer (score 2):

The number of potential triangles containing some specific vertex $v$ is ${n-1 \choose 2}$. Let $[n]$ be the set of vertices of the random graph and let $L = \{ \{s, t\}: s, t \in [n] \setminus \{v\}, s \neq t\}.$ Clearly, $|L| = {n-1 \choose 2}$. Moreover, any triangle containing $v$ corresponds to an element of $L$ and vice versa.

So
$$
\# \text{ of triangles containing }v = \sum_{\{s,t\} \in L} 1_{\{v \sim s \sim t \sim v\}},
$$
where $1_{\{v \sim s \sim t \sim v\}}$ is 1 when all three edges $\{v, s\}, \{s, t\}, \{t, v\}$ are present and 0 otherwise. For any $\{s, t\} \in L$, we have that
$$
E\left[ 1_{\{v \sim s \sim t \sim v\}} \right] = p^3. 
$$
By linearity of expectation,
$$
E\left[\# \text{ of triangles containing }v\right] = \sum_{\{s,t\} \in L} p^3 = {n-1 \choose 2}p^3.
$$
Now this expression can be rewritten as
$$
(n-1)p \, \frac{( (n-1)-1)p}{2} \, p
$$
which is quite similar to your expression.